# How do I use nmcli to display the default route

Tags: nmcli

I am using nmcli version 0.9.10.0

How can I use nmcli to determine the default route - after connecting?

How come the results I see under "Connection Information" (nm-applet) is different to the results of route?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `nmcli d show |  grep gw`

Comment: And add a screenshot of your nm-applet

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my first question! My bad on question 2. The results are the same

Answer (score 2):

Your default gateway is the output of

```
nmcli d show |  grep gw
```

Sample output,

```
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:     ip = 192.168.20.61/24, gw = 192.168.20.11
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:     ip = 2a02:8108:2380:2ef0:99f4:8f6d:f30e:c089/64, gw = fe80::3681:c4ff:feaf:8198
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:     ip = 2a02:8108:2380:2ef0:a00:27ff:fe4f:20ab/64, gw = fe80::3681:c4ff:feaf:8198
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:     ip = fe80::a00:27ff:fe4f:20ab/64, gw = fe80::3681:c4ff:feaf:8198
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:     ip = 127.0.0.1/8, gw = 0.0.0.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:     ip = ::1/128, gw = ::
```

Compare the output with the output of

```
$ ip route | grep default
default via 192.168.20.11 dev eth0  proto static  metric 100
```

Comment: Thanks... not sure what I was looking at. The results are the same.